# Cron expression for every five minutes in the next n hours?

Tags: cron, quartz-scheduler

I know every five minutes is:

```
0 0/5 * * * *
```

But how do I limit the number hours for this to happen?

Example: Every five minutes for the next 10 hours.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think should be able to define a trigger that can repeat every hour until a certain time:

```
import static org.quartz.SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule;
import static org.quartz.TriggerBuilder.newTrigger;

...

Trigger myTrigger = newTrigger()
                    .withIdentity('myUniqueTriggerID")
                    .forJob(myJob)
                    .startAt(startDate)
                    .endAt(endDate)
                    .withSchedule(simpleSchedule().withIntervalInHours(1));

...

scheduler.scheduleJob(myJob, myTrigger);
```

Comment: That is a valid answer. Problem is that my code is client of an EJB that deals with quartz API. I only can provide startTime and cron expression.

Comment: It seems I can't do what I want with a single cron expression.

Comment: Not sure I fully understand the problem. Could you please provide a more detailed explanation of the problem? Also perhaps you could use the `-` special character to define the interval. Take a look at http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.0.0/org/quartz/CronExpression.html

Comment: I don't have control on quartz API. I am just calling an EJB that receives a startTime (date object) and the cron expression. Yes, at the end I used "-" computing the range I should set there. Still thinking about special cases here... like switching from one day to another in a computed range.

Comment: In a general context (having access to the quartz API) your answer is correct.

Answer (score 13):

Use the range operator to specify the hours. For example, for running the job every five minutes for 10 hours starting at 2 am:

```
0 0/5 2-12 * * *
```

Here is an excellent tutorial on Cron expression and operators: 
http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/crontrigger.html

Edit: 10/3/2016: Updated the link.

Comment: Updated the link.

Answer (score 2):

If you can programatically access the `CronTrigger` that is running your cron expression then you can call the methods `setStartTime` and `setEndTime` with the computed time range.

Alternatively you could construct the cron expression on the fly and specify a computed hour range.

For example if you are starting your server at 9am you could create this expression at runtime `0 0/5 9-19 * * *`